# Using binutils size on object file gives a size smaller then the actual size of the object file

Tags: c, compiler-construction

I am working with optimizing a single C object file with regards on the footprint. I'm using the compiler arm-elf-gcc, as the target platform is for a ARM-926EJ processor.

I want to document the current size and then compare after the optimization and I'm wondering, why does arm-elf-size return a size that is smaller then the actual size of the object file?

This is what I get with arm-elf-size

`text     data     bss     dec     hex filename`
`15656   29188       0   44844    af2c  hyper.o`

And the actual size of the hyper.o file is 54 168 bytes.

Which one should i look at?

Best Regards

Mr Gigu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object file has headers which aren't part of the segments sizes reported by elf-size.

Comment: So it's more correct to look at the size returned by arm-elf-size?

Comment: It depends on your purpose.  To know the place really taken in memory, yes (but it can also depend on the placement of the segments in memory).  Note also that when you have uninitialized data, you may end up in the reverse situation (size reports more than the file size).